# Failed to collect and Failed to read artifact

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run a small maven project into my eclipse; and i'm getting this error. Can someone please help?

Failed to execute goal on project JSFExamples: Could not resolve 
    dependencies 
    for project com.ao.courts:JSFExamples:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect 
    dependencies at com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.1.7: Failed to read artifact 
    descriptor for com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.1.7: Could not transfer artifact 
    com.sun.faces:jsf-api:pom:2.1.7 from/to central 
    (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
    valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ao.courts</groupId>
<artifactId>JSFExamples</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>JSFExamples</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: What Java version are you using for Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably inside a company network and your proxy/firewall blocks the access.